# Using Position() in a blog roll to work on every page

Tags: xml, xslt, umbraco

Currently I am using the following xslt code:

```
<xsl:if test="position() = 3">
      <div>
        <object data="/frontpage_blogroll_center_top_728x90" type="text/html" width="735" height="95" style="overflow:hidden; width: 738px; height: 100px"><xsl:comment /></object>
      </div>
    </xsl:if>
```

I'm using "position() = 3" to position an ad in a blog roll, it works for the first page but not for the subsequent pages. (IE ?page=2 ?page=3 etc) Is there anyway to get it to work for all pages?

Comment: You haven't a question here -- the answer is: it doesn't work due to the bad weather... For any XSLT question, you must provide a complete (but minimal) example: complete XML document, the complete wanted result, the complete set of rules the transformation is required to implement.

Comment: Poorly defined question really.

Comment: People often misunderstand what position() does. It's worth reading the spec. The key thing is that it depends on the dynamic context, and you haven't given us any information about the dynamic context of your code fragment, so we can't tell why it's not giving the result you expect.

Comment: Small remark: Mostly every time, dynamic context in Umbraco depens on the usage (applying, iteration) of specific Umbraco's parameter, plus the results of some extension functions. So, from the general XSLT language point of view, those parameters and extensions are unknown. You need an Umbraco developer, rarer than an XSLT one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <xsl:if test="position() = 3 + ($numberOfPosts * number($pageNumber - 1))">
    <div>
      <object data="/frontpage_blogroll_center_top_728x90" type="text/html" width="735" height="95" style="overflow:hidden; width: 738px; height: 100px"><xsl:comment /></object>
    </div>  
 </xsl:if>
```

Just wanted to post the answer